# How do you get the number of elements as an number in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

Let's say I have three spans in a div.

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

And let's say I have some janky code that counts the number of those spans and outputs the value somewhere else

```html
<p>3</p>
```

In cypress I want to get the length of those spans and get the value that I've produced *in my janky code* and compare the two.

I've tried `cy.get('div span').its('length')`, but that yields  the spans as an object...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. `its('length')` will return a number. `<p>3</p>` on invoking text gives a string, adding a + in front will convert it into a number `+count`.

```js
cy.get('div span')
  .its('length')
  .then((len) => {
    cy.get('p')
      .invoke('text')
      .then((count) => {
        expect(len).to.equal(+count)
      })
  })
```

Comment: Why thank you, I've got used to a functional style so much, I'm always looking for ways not to have callbacks or then's in my code.

Didn't think its actually a promise based object, thanks.